# What is this syntax formatting tool?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, formatting

I know this has been out for a while, but I missed the wave, and now I don't know what it's called.

[image]

What plugin is being used here to format the italics, single arrow icon, and combined equal signs? I primarily use VSCode.

Comment: It's a font that uses ligatures.  So not a plugin.  I don't know which font that is though.

Comment: some themes have this italics, like `Winter is Coming`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually not a plug-in -- You're looking for a font that has both **ligatures** *and* **cursive italics**, like **operator mono**. Fair warning, it's not cheap!